# Why does random.choices with weights don't match my expectation?

Tags: python, probability

When I execute this code, I expect both functions to return roughly 0.6. Yet, `always_sunny` returns approx. 0.6 as expected, but `guess_with_weight` returns approx. 0.52 instead.

```py
import random

k = 1000000

def sample():
    return random.choices(population=['rain', 'sunny'], weights=[0.4, 0.6], k=k)

def always_sunny(xs):
    return sum(
        [
            (1 if x == 'sunny' else 0) 
            for x in xs
        ]
    )

def guess_with_weight(xs):
    return sum(
        [
            (1 if x == y else 0) 
            for x, y in zip(xs, sample())
        ]
    )

xs = sample()
print((
    always_sunny(xs)/ k * 1.0,
    guess_with_weight(xs) / k * 1.0
))
```

Why is that? If there is 60% chance of being sunny, and I always guess 'sunny' I should be right 60% of the time, right (and the code agrees). If I instead guess 'rain' 40% of the time, and 'sunny' 60% of the time, shouldn't I also be right 60% of the time? Why does the code suggest I'm only right about 52% of the time?

Comment: Because `0.4 ** 2 + 0.6 ** 2 == 0.52`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60% of the time, the right answer is "sunny".  In 60% of that 60% (36%), you guess "sunny", and you're right, and in 40% of that 60% (24%), you guess "rain", and you're wrong.

40% of the time, the right answer is "rain".  In 60% of 40% (24%) you're wrong, and in 40% of 40% (16%) you're right.

Adding those two scenarios together, we get:

- 36% + 16% = 52% right
- 24% + 24% = 48% wrong

Because "sunny" is the most likely answer, and because the probability of any given element being "sunny" vs "rain" is independent of all the others, "sunny" is *always* the best guess; guessing "sunny" 100% of the time allows you to have a 100% success rate for the 60% of the time that "sunny" is the answer, for an overall success rate of 60%.  Any strategy that doesn't involve guessing "sunny" 100% of the time is therefore going to have a lower success rate than 60%.

Another way to look at it: guessing "sunny" all the time (the best strategy) gets you 60%, and guessing "rain" all the time (the worst strategy) gets you 40%.  Any strategy that involves a mix of guesses is going to land you somewhere in between, proportionate to whatever ratio of best vs worst guesses you make.  52% is exactly 60% of the way from 40% to 60%.